# How to interface emailauthor.jsp

Tags: email

There are many places where some examples about emailauthor.jsp are found. None seems to hold the complete list of parameters.

eg. rtype=003&P3=.. etc.

Where can I find the complete list and how to use it. I need to make a very fast (low clicking) interface for the customer.

Is there an Apex-example as a alternative out there?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but this site provides some documentation on these variables.

http://singhgautam02.blogspot.com/2013/10/quick-fix-how-to-build-url-to-launch.html

I also found this solved my problem of getting an attachment added to my VF email template.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008xy3IAA